# Regex to match after specific characters

Tags: c#, regex

```
var str = "=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Metadata1.Value),"N/A",Fields!Metadata1.Value)";
var regexp = new Regex(@"Fields!(\w+)");
var matches = regexp.Matches(str);
```

The matches will have "Fields!Metadata1"
while I need to get "Metadata1"

What shall I change?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

don't know c# syntax, for regex, try:

```
(?<=Fields!)\w*
```

**EDIT** add short explanation:

`(?<=foo)bar`  matches `bar` only if `bar` is following `foo` (foo is not gonna in  match result) `(?<=..)` is positive look behind, zero-width assertion. google it for details.

Comment: Works great. Thanks! I am new to regexp. Could you please explain what this one is doing?

Answer (score 10):

What you need is called **lookbehind/lookahead**. Regex has [this feature](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can specify what follows (or in this case preceeds) the currently matched string.

`[0-9](?=[a-z])` will match any one digit followed by a lowercase letter.
`[0-9](?![a-z])` will match any one digit NOT followed by a lowercase letter. (this is called a negative lookahead)
`(?<=[a-z])[0-9]` will match any one digit preceeded by a lowercase letter.
`(?<![a-z])[0-9]` will match any one digit NOT preceeded by a lowercase letter.(this is called a negative lookbehind)

With that in mind, the c# expression you want is:

```
var str = "=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Metadata1.Value),"N/A",Fields!Metadata1.Value)";
var regexp = new Regex(@"(?<=Fields!)(\w+)");
var matches = regexp.Matches(str);
```

**EDIT:** this is good for you if you **DON'T want to match** the "Fields!" part. A slightly different task is if you want to match it, but you *also need the second part's value*. In which case, I recommend using [named groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html), which will capture the entire thing, but you can get the part from the Groups collection. The regex in that case will be: `Fields!(?'fieldName'\w+)`, and the c# usage is

```
var str = "=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Metadata1.Value),"N/A",Fields!Metadata1.Value)";
var regexp = new Regex(@"Fields!(?'fieldName'\w+)");
var matches = regexp.Matches(str);
foreach (Match m in matches) 
{
   var fieldName = m.Groups["fieldName"].Value;
   //...
}
```

Comment: C# named groups are given by angle brackets, not quotes... But named groups aren't really necessary here anyway, and the original regex already has a capturing group.

Comment: as for named groups vs capturing groups: I find it's always better to work with names instead of indexes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is very detailed answer. It is a pity I cannot accept both the first correct and the most detailed one. Thanks again

Comment: Huh, today I learned about `'...'` instead of `<...>`. But still, in such a simple regular expression, with only one group...

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try this...

var match = Regex.Match(item, @"!(\w+)");

then get the match.Groups[1].Value