# Need to get so substring but using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I got on url like.

```
http://EddyFox.com/x/xynua
```

Need to fetch substring after `/x/` what ever string is there.

complex example I faced is :

```
http://EddyFox.com/x//x/
```

Here result should be `/x/`

It can be achieved with substring ,But we need to perform it with regular expression.

Comment: "we need to perform it with regular expression" why?

Comment: will it alsways be 'http://EddyFox.com/x/..' ?

Comment: What exact trouble did you have with your pattern? Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I tried this one ^(https?://)?(www\.)?([^:/]+)(:[0-9]+)?(/|/t/)?(.*)?$

Comment: Why `/t/` if you have `/x/`? Also, adding `?` after `(/|/t/)?` makes it optional. Do you need to match the whole string? I mean, you do not really need `^(https?...)?` and the rest. What you asked for is just `Regex.Match(input, @"/x/(.*)").Groups[1].Value`

Comment: yes it is with x i was trying it examplary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
string s = "http://EddyFox.com/x/xynua";
// I guess you don't want the /x/ in your match ?=!
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(s, "/x/(.*)").Groups[1].Value );
```

this is probably even better:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(s, "(?<=/x/)(.*)").Value );
```

the output is

> xynua

Have a look at this post: [Regex to match after specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025545/regex-to-match-after-specific-characters) SO is full of RegEx posts. The probability is very high that a RegEx question has already been asked before. :)

Comment: Ya right Mong zhu, There might have other question like this. my mistake.  Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(s, "(?<=/x/)(.*)").Value ); this worked for me.

Comment: @HarishVirodhia glad to hear.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `/x/(.*)` will capture everything following the `/x/`

Answer (score 0):

And where is the problem?

```
var r = new Regex("/x/(\\S*)");
var matches = r.Matches(myUrl);
```

This regex matches everything from `/x/` until the first occurence of a white-space.