# How do I match anything that comes AFTER an exact match, while not including the match itself?

Tags: c#, regex

For example:

```
/\/r\/.*/i
```

This works, but it also returns "/r/", which I do not want. Also, that is not written in C#, it's just an example.

The idea is to retrieve the keyword of a subreddit URL, as in "funny" in "/r/funny".

Comment: `(?<=\/r\/)[^\/]+`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/TqpjpG/1

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting the text that follows after the regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006716/getting-the-text-that-follows-after-the-regex-match), [Regex to match after specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15025545/8967612).

Comment: Thank you. What is that doing?

Comment: `(?<=...)` is called a (positive) Lookbehind. Check the linked post. As to `^[\/]+`, it's similar to `.+` except that it matches everything _except_ the `/` character.